# transforming object array into parent child relation

Tags: javascript

I am tring to convert `vm.scholasticlist` into `vm.parentList2`.
In `vm.scholasticlist`, ***s_gid*** is unique key, and ***parent_id*** point to parent ***s_gid***.

vm.scholasticlist is what I am getting from WebService as return. 
I am trying following javascript code, but unable to build it.

```
vm.scholasticlist = [];
vm.parentList = [];
vm.parentList2 = [];

for (var i in vm.scholasticlist) {
    if(vm.scholasticlist[i]['parent_id'] == 0 ){
        vm.parentList.push(vm.scholasticlist[i])
    }
}


vm.parentList2 = vm.parentList;

for (var i in vm.parentList) {

    console.log(vm.parentList[i]['s_gid'])
    for (var x in vm.scholasticlist) {
        if(vm.scholasticlist[x]['parent_id'] === vm.parentList[i]['s_gid'] ){
            console.log(vm.parentList[i]['s_gid'])
            vm.parentList2.push(vm.scholasticlist[x])
        }
    }
}

vm.scholasticlist = [{
    "s_gid": "10",
    "m_s_p_id": "1",
    "subject_group_name": "Foundation of Information Technology",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "sname": ""
}, {
    "s_gid": "11",
    "m_s_p_id": "2",
    "subject_group_name": "Life Skills",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "sname": ""
}, {
    "s_gid": "15",
    "m_s_p_id": "2",
    "subject_group_name": "Thinking Skills",
    "parent_id": "11",
    "sname": "Th.sk"
}, {
    "s_gid": "15",
    "m_s_p_id": "2",
    "subject_group_name": "Thinking Skills",
    "parent_id": "11",
    "sname": "Th.sk"
}]
```

want to build new JSON with parent child relation

```
vm.parentList2 = [{
    "s_gid": "10",
    "m_s_p_id": "1",
    "subject_group_name": "Foundation of Information Technology",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "sname": ""
}, {
    "s_gid": "11",
    "m_s_p_id": "2",
    "subject_group_name": "Life Skills",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "sname": "",
    "child": [{
        "s_gid": "15",
        "m_s_p_id": "2",
        "subject_group_name": "Thinking Skills",
        "parent_id": "11",
        "sname": "Th.sk"
    }, {
        "s_gid": "15",
        "m_s_p_id": "2",
        "subject_group_name": "Thinking Skills",
        "parent_id": "11",
        "sname": "Th.sk"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: I don't really see any JSON, it all looks like javascript to me ?

Comment: @adeneo, yes, I am trying to build new JSON array based on fist one with parent child relation with JAVASCRIPT. first JSON array is response of webservice without parent child.

Comment: @fresher: It's not JSON, it's just Javascript objects. JSON is a *string*, what you have are object literals. The talk of JSON is totally irrelevant to your question.

Comment: *"I am trying following javascript code, but unable to build it."* what does it do? Does it give you errors? Is it not structured the way you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
scholasticlist = [{
    "s_gid": "10",
    "m_s_p_id": "1",
    "subject_group_name": "Foundation of Information Technology",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "sname": ""
}, {
    "s_gid": "11",
    "m_s_p_id": "2",
    "subject_group_name": "Life Skills",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "sname": ""
}, {
    "s_gid": "15",
    "m_s_p_id": "2",
    "subject_group_name": "Thinking Skills",
    "parent_id": "11",
    "sname": "Th.sk"
}, {
    "s_gid": "15",
    "m_s_p_id": "2",
    "subject_group_name": "Thinking Skills",
    "parent_id": "11",
    "sname": "Th.sk"
}];

// first convert your original array into a dictionary. That way we can do quick
// lookups by id
var dict = scholasticlist.reduce(function(p,c) {
    p[c.s_gid] = c;
    return p;
},{});

// then just go through your list again and push items into an array
var parentList2 = scholasticlist.reduce(function(p,c) {
    if (c.parent_id === "0") {     // has no parent
        p.push(c);
    } else {                       // has a parent, so we find it and then add to
                                   // the children
        if (!dict[c.parent_id].child) { // really ought to be children - it's an array!
            dict[c.parent_id].child = [];
        }
        dict[c.parent_id].child.push(c);
    }
    return p;
},[]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(parentList2, null, 2));
```

Comment: is it possible to put in front of each subject_group_name a sign like "-" base upon depth of child. for example first child "-" , second level child "--" etc

Comment: @fresher: Sure, but that's an entirely different question.

Comment: True. it is. I tried manipulating your code, but it put only single "-" for all child. Can you help pls.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this function -- it uses ES6 syntax:

```js
function buildTree(list) {
    // create a hash for the array. 
    // Start with a "root" entry for linking nodes with parentid = 0:
    var hash = { '0': { child: [] } };
    list.forEach( obj => hash[obj.s_gid] = Object.assign(obj, { child: [] }) );
    
    // move items into the appropriate child array
    list.forEach( obj => hash[obj.parent_id].child.push(obj) );
    
    // return the child array in the root element:
    return hash['0'].child;
}

//  Sample data
var vm = {};
vm.scholasticlist = [{
    "s_gid": "10",
    "m_s_p_id": "1",
    "subject_group_name": "Foundation of Information Technology",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "sname": ""
}, {
    "s_gid": "11",
    "m_s_p_id": "2",
    "subject_group_name": "Life Skills",
    "parent_id": "0",
    "sname": ""
}, {
    "s_gid": "15",
    "m_s_p_id": "2",
    "subject_group_name": "Thinking Skills",
    "parent_id": "11",
    "sname": "Th.sk"
}, {
    "s_gid": "15",
    "m_s_p_id": "2",
    "subject_group_name": "Thinking Skills",
    "parent_id": "11",
    "sname": "Th.sk"
}];

// Transform to tree
vm.scholasticlist = buildTree(vm.scholasticlist);

// Output result
console.log(vm.scholasticlist);
```